# innerHTML on a style element causing runtime error

Tags: html, css, innerhtml

This works in FF safari and chrome but is causing an error in IE8

```
var styleText = "#" + containerElement.id + " button {background-color:" + options.bg_color + ";}";
    styleText += "#" + containerElement.id + " button.not-open {color:" + options.txt_color + ";}";
    styleText += "#" + containerElement.id + " button.not-open:hover {color:" + options.hvr_color + ";}";
    styleText += ".info_pane {background-color:" + options.bg_color + ";}";
    styleText += ".info_pane {color:" + options.txt_color + ";}";
    styleText += ".info_pane a {color:" + options.txt_color + ";}";
    var style = document.createElement('style');
    style.type = 'text/css';
    style.innerHTML = styleText;
```

the innerHTML is what is throwing the error. What would be the best alternative to making this work? I have looked around and most things i have found seem a little shaky

Comment: document.write will be best alternative

Comment: i tried 
  document.write('<style type="text/css">');
  document.write(styleText);
  document.write('</style>'); What do i do instead? this made nothing on my page appear haha

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try the `cssText` property instead. `style.cssText = styleText;`

EDIT: Evidently, that would be `style.styleSheet.cssText = styleText;`. My bad.

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/vArSa/)

Comment: i think this isn't working because 'style' object is a <style></style> element on the page that i am appending to the head of my document. I am not trying to change the style of the 'style' element

Answer (score 1):

```
    var styleText = "#" + containerElement.id + " button {background-color:" + options.bg_color + ";}";
    styleText += "#" + containerElement.id + " button.not-open {color:" + options.txt_color + ";}";
    styleText += "#" + containerElement.id + " button.not-open:hover {color:" + options.hvr_color + ";}";
    styleText += ".info_pane {background-color:" + options.bg_color + ";}";
    styleText += ".info_pane {color:" + options.txt_color + ";}";
    styleText += ".info_pane a {color:" + options.txt_color + ";}";
    var style = document.createElement('style');
    style.type = 'text/css';
    if(style.styleSheet) { //IE
        style.styleSheet.cssText = styleText;
        document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(style);
    } else {
        style.innerHTML = styleText;
        document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(style);
    }
```

This is what i ended up having to go with. Don't remember exactly where i found it, but it works.

Answer (score 0):

Glad you found a solution... just out of interest, what do you get if you try any of the following?

```
style.innerText = styleText;
style.insertAdjacentText('beforeEnd', styleText);
style.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeEnd', styleText);
style.replaceAdjacentText('beforeEnd', styleText);
```

I don't have access to an IE8 user agent at the moment to test and was just pondering. According to msdn neither [innerHTML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms533897%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), nor [insertAdjacentHTML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms536452%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is supported on a [Style](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ie/ms535898%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) element *(rather ridiculously)*... however it does support [replaceAdjacentText](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ie/ms536714%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)?? good old IE as usual.

I guess another fallback -- just for ideas sake -- is to use:

```
var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
    head.insertAdjacentHTML('<style>'+styleText+'</style>');
```